# Find all email addresses corresponding to an ambiguous name

Tags: vba, email, outlook

User has a column with names (or name, surname) to send email.
When there are several with the same name and surname the macro is selecting the first matching.
How can I check if for a specific name there is more than one email addresse, to perform another function?
My code to get email address.

```
    Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Namespace
    Dim myAddrList As AddressList
    Dim myAddrEntry As AddressEntry
    Dim AliasName As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim EndRow As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim exchUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
    
    Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myNameSpace = myolApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myAddrList = myNameSpace.AddressLists("Global Address List")
    
    EndRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each c In Range("A1:A" & CStr(EndRow))
    
        AliasName = LCase(Trim(c))
        c = AliasName
        Set myAddrEntry = myAddrList.AddressEntries(AliasName)
        Set exchUser = myAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser
        On Error Resume Next
       
        c.Offset(0, 4) = exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
        
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula in Excel sheet =COUNTIF(column_range, name_surname) and then you can read values with your VBA code. When result of formula is >1 then you do some other procedure.

*Hopefully all your names are sorted in some way first name and then surname or something, sometimes happens that they are mixed and then this aproach might not work correctly.*

Answer (score 0):

There nothing really in Outlook Object Model that would help you with ambiguous names. You can of course loop through all items in GAL (`Namespace.GetGlobalAddressList`), but large GAL containers would not even let you loop through its entries; and if you can loop, it can take a very long time (as in tens of minutes).

Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) lets you either retrieve the list of ambiguous names or display the dialog box that lets you select one entry from the list of ambiguous names. If VBA is your only option, you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) which exposes that MAPI functionality:

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = myolApp.Session.MAPIOBJECT

  'silently retrieve the list matches
  set AdrrEntries = Session.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveNameEx("john")
  MsgBox AdrrEntries.Count & " names were returned by ResolveNameEx:"
  for each AE in AdrrEntries
    MsgBox AE.Name
  next

  'allow Outlook to display the ambiguous name dialog if necessary
  set Match = Session.AddressBook.ResolveName("john", true)
  if not (match is Nothing) Then
    MsgBox match.Name
  End If
```